# Novice iptables misconfiguration with stated rules

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I was configuring a server, and I tried instituting what I thought were some pretty simple iptables rules:

```
[root host ~]
- iptables -L 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             loopback/8          reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

[root host ~] 
- iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Which resulted in the hanging of my SSH session.  Now I can't access the machine by SSH at all, but all the other allowances (HTTP etc.) seem to be working fine.

I did a little more research after the fact, but this still looks like a correct configuration to me.

It seems to me that I've misunderstood the stated filtering iptables offers.  Is that so?  What's wrong with this picture?

EDIT: I adapted my rules from [the debian iptables article](http://wiki.debian.org/iptables), so you can see the original input lines there.

DOUBLE EDIT:  I should be doing the leg work here; I've recreated the original inputs from the Debian article

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: The `iptables -L` output can be incomplete.  For example, it omits interface information.  Can you post `iptables-save` output, too?

Comment: Apparently you can also get verbose output out of `iptables` with `iptables -Lv`.

Comment: I usually do use `-L -v` for exactly that reason, but the same poor planning that has me locked out also keeps me from accessing the detailed data.  You'll have to take my word that topmost `INPUT` rule has `-i lo`, and the second has `! -i lo`, and none of the others have any interface references at all.

Comment: Actually, you can see the original input lines in the link I added to my question.

Comment: Add `-v` to your `iptables` command to get complete information. Also consider using `-n` (numeric) to prevent any unnecessary DNS lookups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was my second rule:

```
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT
```

I foolishly didn't double-check the interfaces on the VPS, and since it's OpenVZ based, an internal vm interface had the address 127.0.0.2 but wasn't technically loopback which tripped this rule.

EDIT:  Nope; I'm wrong again!  It turned out finally to actually be that my VPS allowed insertion of state based rules but never matched them, so established connections were getting dropped when I set the policy to DROP.

Answer (score 0):

This rule is quite suspicious:

```
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             loopback/8          reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Unless you've made sure it doesn't apply to the loopback interface (lo) it'll probably break all sorts of stuff.

Comment: I would imagine so, but the rule is for all interfaces but loopback.  The symptom is hanging connections, so given that this is REJECT, I'd expect it to have a more immediate effect.